# How to open fullscreen mode from another place (html5gallery)

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I use html5gallery (http://html5box.com/html5gallery) as jquery plugn for image gallery.
It has a button which open image gallery in full screen mode (like LightBox).
[image: Screenshot:]

I need to make a way to open fullscreen mode from another place on page. E.g. the first image is shown on top of page, the gallery - on bottom. I want to make a way to open a fullscreen mode by clicking on top icon. I don't found this feature in the help document on official site. Can you help me?

Thanks.